# What is the best way to serialize a ModelForm object in Django?

Tags: python, xml, django, json, serialization

I am using Django and the Google Web Toolkit (GWT) for my current project. I would like to pass a ModelForm instance to GWT via an Http response so that I can "chop" it up and render it as I please. My goal is to keep the form in sync with changes to my models.py file, yet increase control I have over the look of the form. However, the django classes for serialization, serializers and simplejson, cannot serialize a ModelForm. Neither can cPickle. What are my alternatives?

Comment: To "keep the form in sync with changes to my models.py", wouldn't you need to implement something of an equivalent of django.forms in the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using pure Django, you'd pass the form to your template, and could then call individual fields on the form for more precise rendering, rather than using ModelForm.to_table.  You can use the following to iterate over each field and render it exactly how you want:

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
    <div class="form-field">{{ field }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This also affords you the ability to do conditional checks using {% if %} blocks inside the loop should you want to exclude certain fields.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to serialze a ModelForm to json, just write your own simplejson serializer subclass.